# Observable and dependency injection in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a service in like an this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private contentHeader: Headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"});   

    constructor(public events: Events, private authHttp: AuthHttp){

    }

    public get(url): Observable<any> {            
        return this.authHttp.get(url, { headers: this.contentHeader })
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }


    public extractData(res: Response) {
        try {
            let body = res.json();
            return body || {};
        }
        catch (e) {
            return {};
        }
    }

    public handleError(error: any) {
        if (error.status == 401 || error.status == 403)
        {
            // injected
            this.events.publish('user:logout');
        }

        return Observable.throw(error);
    }

}
```

this.events not work inside of handleError and trigger this error in console: EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.events is undefined

How can i use my services with dependency injection inside of map and catch section of Observable?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use arrow function to retain context

```
.catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
```

or

```
public handleError = (error: any) => {
  ...  
}
```

or use `bind` method

```
.catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

See more details about *lexical this* here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this